# Optimization Routine for Logistic Regression in ML (Spark 1.6.2)

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-ml

Dear Apache Spark Comunity:

I've been reading Spark's documentation several weeks. I read Logistic Regression in MLlib and I realized that Spark uses two kinds of optimizations routines (SGD and L-BFGS).

But, currently I'm reading the documentation of LogistReg in ML. I couldn't see explicitly what kind of optimization routine devlopers used. How can I request this information?

With many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The great point is about the API that they are using.

The MlLib is focus in RDD API. The core of Spark, but some of the process like Sums, Avgs and other kind of simple functions take more time thatn the DataFrame process.

The ML is a library that works with dataframe. That dataFrame has the query optimization for basic functions like sums and some kind close of that.

You can check this blog [post](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/24/recent-performance-improvements-in-apache-spark-sql-python-dataframes-and-more.html) and this is one of the reasons that ML should be faster than MlLib.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that was not my question. How can I know what kind of optimization rutine are developers using in Logistic regression (ML)?

For example, in this algorithm description (http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/ml-classification-regression.html#multilayer-perceptron-classifier) they write specifically the optimization routine... "We use logistic loss function for optimization and L-BFGS as optimization routine."

Comment: Understood! Sorry! I will check for that hold on!